# Prepend irregular xts with zeros

Tags: r, xts

I need to add two irregular time series (covering business days).

I have two xts series for two different products A + B.

Product B has data from a later startup-date than A.

I think I need to prepend B so that the dates matches A, but with all zeroes.

Such that sum(A + B) equals sum(A) + sum(B)

*Product A*

```
2009-05-02  4
2010-02-03  4
```

*Product B*

```
2010-02-03  4
```

*Sum:*

```
A + B
2010-02-03  8
```

*Desired result*

```
2009-05-02  4
2010-02-03  8
```

Comment: Can you please post some example data?  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/602276 for tips to write a great question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How's this?

```
library(xts)
```

Fist we need some sample data.

```
proda <- as.xts(matrix(c(4,4), ncol = 1, dimnames = list(c("2009-05-02", "2010-02-03"))))
prodb <- as.xts(matrix(4, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(c("2010-02-03"))))
```

Based on (common) row names, `merge` will link the two created data sets.

```
ab <- merge(proda, prodb)
```

I used `apply` to sum values per each row (`MARGIN = 1`) but `rowSums` would work also.

```
data.frame(val = apply(X = ab, MARGIN = 1, FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Result:

```
           val
2009-05-02   4
2010-02-03   8
```

Comment: One point of clarification: `merge.xts` merges on the index attribute, not row names (like `merge.data.frame`).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a one-liner (using @Roman's example data):

```
with(merge(proda,prodb,fill=0), proda+prodb)
#            proda
# 2009-05-02     4
# 2010-02-03     8
```

`merge.xts` has `all=TRUE` as a default and the `fill=` argument allows you to specify the values to be used for missing elements (default is `fill=NA`).

The result of `merge(proda,prodb,fill=0)` is an object with two columns ("proda","prodb") and an index value for every index value in any of the objects passed to `merge.xts`.